# Unique CSS layout, part of calendar

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a CSS layout going using a minimal amount of css. Currently I have it working, but it's a mess. It's part of a calendar where a user can track his or her weight. But that's not really important, trying to figure out how to make this layout cleaner would be nice!

The concept is attached. Currently I have div's and spans everywhere. The number in the top left of the cell is a div along the top.

In the middle, I have three elements centered. The first is a blank gif that is the size of the icon on the other side. The middle is a text input box. The icon on the right is an image. Since I want everything to be centered, this is how I did it. The invisible gif on the left of the text box, being the same size as the icon, ensures it's centered. Those three elements are contained in a div that is centered.

At the bottom I have two side by side div's, one floated left and the other floated right. Those are contained in a div. A rough idea of the code I am using is below, and a picture of the concept. It's a mess, is there a better way to do this?

```
<td>
    <div class='topleft'>12</div>
    <div class='main'>
        <div class='entry'>
            <span id='blankgif'><blank gif img here></span>
            <input type='text'>
            <span id='icon'><icon here></span>
        </div>
        <div class='info'>
            <div class='info_left' floated left width 49%></div>
            <div class='info_right' floated right width 49%></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: there are many ways to accomplish this. in my opinion your best bet is to create a grid system, or use an established one like Bootstrap

Comment: Can you please show the CSS as well as the HTML? Also, please could you include more of the HTML? It looks like you have a table-cell here  already but the surrounding HTML context is important. Lastly, which browsers do you need to support? There are some CSS3 features that could be helpful with this layout.